# Problem with SQl_satements in Pervasive-Database

Tags: pervasive

The statement

select * from MWlog

works correctly

while with  the statement:

select * from MWlog where Probe= '230541'

Occurse the following error:
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
select * from MWlog where Probe= '230541'
[LNA][Zen][SQL Engine][Data Record Manager]The application encountered an I/O error(Btrieve Error 2)

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > 

Hint:
We use the Zen-Version:

Zen Control Center

Zen Install Version 14.10.035.

Java Version 1.8.0_222.

Copyright © 2020 Actian Corporation

The same error occurs with an elder version:

Answer (score 0):

If it only occurs when using the 'Probe' field, it is possible the index is corrupt.  I would suggest rebuilding the file. You can use the BUTIL -CLONE and -COPY commands or the Rebuild Utility.  I prefer BUTIL -CLONE/COPY.

The status 2 is defined (on https://docs.actian.com/zen/v14/index.html#page/codes%2F1statcod.htm%23ww178919) as:

```
2: The application encountered an I/O error This status code typically indicates a corrupt file, an error while reading from or writing to the disk. One of the following has occurred: 
• The file is damaged, and you must recover it. See Advanced Operations Guide for more information on recovering files. •For pre-v6.0 data files, there is a large pre-image file inside a transaction, and there is not enough disk space for a write to the pre-image file. 
• For pre-v6.0 data files, there is one pre-image file for multiple data files. For example, if you name the data files customer.one and customer.two, both files have pre-image files named customer.pre. 
• For pre-v6.0 data files that are larger than 768 MB, there is a conflict among locking mechanisms. The file has not been corrupted. Your application can retry the operation until the conflict is resolved (when the competing application releases the lock your application requires). 
• A pre-v6.0 Btrieve engine attempted to open a v6.x or later MicroKernel file. 
• With Btrieve for Windows NT Server Edition v6.15.445, 32 bit Windows application may return Status 2 or “MKDE Terminated with Service Specific Error 0” after running an application for an extended period of time.
```